# Is $\sqrt{n}$ polynomially larger than $\log{n}$?

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, asymptotics, computational-complexity

For functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, $f(x)$ is polynomially larger than $g(x)$ if $f(x)$ is asymptotically larger than $g(x)$ by a factor of $n^{\epsilon}$ for some constant $\epsilon > 0$.

$\lim_{n \rightarrow  \infty} \frac{\sqrt{n}}{\log{n}} = \infty$ tells me that $\sqrt{n}$ is asymptotically larger than $\log{n}$, but I am stuck determining whether or not it is polynomially larger. If $\sqrt{n}$ is polynomially larger than $\log{n}$, how can I find a factor $n^{\epsilon}$?

Comment: Hint: $\sqrt{n} = n^{1/2}$. Does that tell you anything about how large you can pick $\epsilon$?

Comment: You can choose any $\epsilon$ with $0 \lt \epsilon \lt \frac12$. Choosing $\epsilon=\frac13$ or $\frac14$ would make the expressions simpler than many other choices

Comment: Intuitively, you can think of those functions in terms of their opposites: the opposite of square root is squaring and the opposite of logarithm is exponentiation. Since exponentiation "grows" much faster than squaring, you can deduce that their opposites act reversely: $\lim_{n \rightarrow  \infty} \frac{n^2}{a^n} = 0  \implies \lim_{n \rightarrow  \infty} \frac{\sqrt{n}}{\log{n}} = \infty$, for any real $a>1$

Comment: See this discussion for a more general case. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4376994/are-polynomials-always-asymptotically-larger-than-polylogarithms?noredirect=1#comment9147168_4376994

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since both the numerator and denominator go to $\infty$ as $n \to \infty$, we may apply de l'Hôpital's rule:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{n}}{\log n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}}{\frac{1}{n}}  = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{n}}{2} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^{1/2}}{2}$$
This tells you that you can pick $\epsilon \in (0,1/2)$.

Answer (score 0):

It is also true that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}{\frac{n^\frac14}{\log n}}=\infty$$
Thus
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}{\frac{n^\frac12}{n^\frac14\log n}}=\infty$$