# Are polynomials *always* asymptotically larger than polylogarithms?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, computational-complexity

Is it always the case that asymptotically, for any $c,d>0$ it holds that $n^c$ is asymptotically larger than log$^d(n)$?

That is, if $f=O(n^c)$ and $g=\Omega(log^d(n))$, is $f/g$ unbounded as $n\rightarrow\infty?$

Comment: To show that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{n^c}{\log^d n} = \infty$ it is enough to show that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{n^c}{\log n} = \infty$  -- just replace $c$ with $\frac{c}{d}$.

Comment: Yes, it's always true. Since $n^c = e^{c\log(n)}$, it's equivalent to the more common statement that exponentials grow faster than polynomials.